# Could not find WCT plugin named "local" when running Polymer test

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit, web-component-tester

After cloning Polymer Starter Kit, I installed WCT with:

```
npm install -g web-component-tester
```

Now, I am getting this error:

> Could not find WCT plugin named "local"

How do I fix this?

Comment: same here, propably with much more newer version of bower, polymer-cli and WCT and still, I have same problem. Would be great if someone responsed to this question